# Django form - in-place edit of data from reverse foreign key join

Tags: django, forms, foreign-keys, reverse

I have a Person table and Phone table.  The Phone table has a foreign key into the Person table, which is an auto-increment ID.  Each person can have an arbitrary number of phone numbers.  Is there a way for me to create a Django form to enter phone numbers while creating a new Person entry and edit them along with an existing Person entry?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, Django's inlineformset_factory is exactly what you need.

Docs: [Model Formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#id1) and [Inline formsets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)

[This snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1246/) should help you as an example.